# C type casting from a Ua_Variant

Tags: c, pointers, open62541

I'm trying to understand what the typecasting is doing in the following code

```
UA_Variant Variant; 
Int32_t Variable; 

variable = *(int32_t *) Variant.data; 
printf("%d", variable);
```

This is the structure of the UA_Variant

```
typedef struct 
{
    const UA_DataType *type;      /* The data type description */
    UA_VariantStorageType storageType;
    size_t arrayLength;           /* The number of elements in the data array */
    void *data;                   /* Points to the scalar or array data */
    size_t arrayDimensionsSize;   /* The number of dimensions */
    UA_UInt32 *arrayDimensions;   /* The length of each dimension */
} UA_Variant;
```

What is happening in this line

```
variable = *(int32_t *) Variant.data;
```

is it type casting the data in Variant to int32_t then taking the pointer of that into the variable and if so why can I print out the value stored in variable?

Answer (score 3):

Let's unpack this statement in multiple steps: `*(int32_t *) Variant.data`

First, we have `Variant.data` which is a `void*` according to the `UA_Variant` struct. This means that it is simply a number containing a memory address.

Then, with `(int32_t *)` you cast that `void*` to a `int32_t*`. The data pointed to by `Variant.data` will then be interpreted as a pointer to data of type `int32_t`. **I insist on interpreted not casted.**

Finaly, you dereference it with the `*` operator. As a result, the variable `variable` contains the data pointed to by `Variant.data` interpreted as a signed 32 bit value. This means that if the data pointed to by `Variant.data` was some other datatype like a `float`s, the resulting value in your variable would seem random and depend on undefined behavior. This is because different platforms implement each datatype differently.

Since this variable is a value, you can print it like any other.

Comment: Thanks, think I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` member of your `UA_Variant` structure is defined as `void*`, which means it points to an object *unspecified* type. Such "void pointers" cannot be dereferenced.

So, if the particular `data` member of your `Variant` points to an object that is to be treated as an object of `int32_t` type, then the pointer *itself* must first be cast to the correct pointer type (`int32_t*`); then, it can be dereferenced.

The line `variable = *(int32_t *) Variant.data;` is perhaps more readily understandable with some added parentheses. This is equivalent code:

```c
variable = *( (int32_t *)(Variant.data) );
```